# Flutter gives error by using Drift after Moor

Tags: flutter, caching, flutter-dependencies

I had tried flutter clean but error did not go.I used Moor 4.6.1 version and after that this error occured

```
C:\Users\LENOVO\development\projects\ToDo_App>flutter packages run build_runner build

[SEVERE] drift_dev:drift_dev on lib/custom_widget/tasks_tile.dart (cached):

InconsistentAnalysisException: Requested result might be inconsistent with previously ret
urned results

[SEVERE] drift_dev:drift_dev on lib/modals/task.dart (cached):

InconsistentAnalysisException: Requested result might be inconsistent with previously ret
urned results

[SEVERE] drift_dev:drift_dev on lib/custom_widget/tasks_list.dart (cached):

InconsistentAnalysisException: Requested result might be inconsistent with previously ret
urned results

[SEVERE] Failed after 11.5s
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: try running with --delete conflicts flags `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: I have noticed the same issue today, I tried to migrate moor to drift and got the same problem

Comment: have a look at this issue https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/3271

Comment: @demsey that solved my problem. I had downgraded the build_runner and analyzer. Thanks buddy
But I also need your advice in building a dynamic form whose fields will be sent by the admin from the firebase and I have to build a form in mobile app and send the details of the form. If you give any workflow advice how to approach that problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to do:
First:  downgrade the build_runner version to 2.1.6 or 2.1.5

```
dev_dependencies:
    build_runner: 2.1.6
```

Second: also downgrade the analyzer version

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: 3.3.1
```